# Just switched from windows 10 Pro to Linux Miint 20. Realtek Optical Digital Audio Output not working?

Tags: linux-mint, audio

How do I trouble shoot Optical digital audio output on Linux Mint 20?

---

If I click on the speaker and then open settings there is no digital optical output device. I have a Yamaha receiver connected to the optical port on back of PC and see nothing in audio output settings? Shouldn't there be a picture of a receiver or the name of receiver in the output list?

Comment: i read a bit of your post ... you said that optical out does not work with windows and it does not work with linux ... how do you actually know that optical out does not work?

Comment: I plugged the opyical cable into another device and it works. I dont see that optical output when I click on the speaker on bottom right corner of screen.

Comment: what do you hope to accomplish by posting here? ... you said that the optical output stopped working during the time that you had windows installed on your computer ... installing linux did not resolve the issue ... my first guess is that you have hardware failure .... take your computer to have it checked by a technician

Comment: voting to close because hardware failure is very likely the cause

Answer (score 1):

The S/PDIF optical audio output is strictly one-way: there is no way for the sending device to get any information about the properties of the receiving device, not even whether or not there *is* one in the first place.

In Linux, most Realtek audio chips with a S/PDIF output (as far as I've seen) include a S/PDIF output switch within the ALSA mixer settings. On modern Linux distributions there is usually Pulseaudio layered on top of ALSA, so just running `alsamixer` will display the simplified Pulseaudio mixer controls. But if you explicitly specify the sound card number, you can still access the full ALSA mixer functionality, including the S/PDIF output switch(es).

First, run `cat /proc/asound/cards`. This will display all your current ALSA sound devices and the device numbers associated with them. Find the number of your integrated sound chip: it might be something like `HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH`. (Most modern sound chips follow the Intel HD-Audio standard: the name "Realtek" is not necessarily visible here.)

Then, run `alsamixer -c X`, replacing `X` with the actual number of your sound device. If you have just one sound device, it will most likely be `0`.

You will see a terminal-based sound mixer display with a number of sliders. The display may be wider than your terminal: use the left and right arrow keys to move between the sliders (and scroll sideways as necessary), and up & down arrows to adjust the volume. Many sliders will also have a "mute" toggle at the bottom of the slider, switchable using the <kbd>M</kbd> key.

You'll want to move to the right until you find one or more columns with no actual slider, but just the "mute" toggle in them. Their label should include "S/PDIF". Toggle them all to the opposite state, and your optical output should activate.

If there are multiple S/PDIF toggles, it may take a bit of testing to find out which of them exactly controls the optical output.

You might be able to use the `alsactl store` command to persistently store your ALSA-level mixer settings, although your desktop environment may interfere with this as it might attempt to save/restore the ALSA-level settings on its own too.